# Navigation should pop back stack instead of returning to start destination

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

My `Activity` has a `NavHostFragment` and a `BottomNavigationView` in its layout. The `NavHostFragment` has a `main_navigation_graph` which contains four `Fragments` in it. Their `ids` matching the `BottomNavigationView#menu` so that the `Navigation` can handle all the stuff by itself when I call

```
activity_main_bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Everything works so far. 
My problem is that the **back button** will go to the **start destination** when another tab (in the BottomBar) was selected.

I know that is the intended behaviour (at least according to the `NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected` documentation):

> ...
>
> By default, the back stack will be popped back to the navigation graph's start destination.
>    Menu items that have `android:menuCategory="secondary"` will not pop the back stack.

But that isn't what I want .

I want the behaviour like

> If the user is at the "root" of a tab (from the BottomNavigation) **and** the user presses back -> close the `App` (finish the `Activity`).

How can I achieve that?

This gif demonstrates the current implementation:

[image]

When I at the **Szenen** tab and press **back** I want to close the `Activity`. Instead it goes to the `startDestination` (which is the **System** tab).

Comment: gif is not working

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: can't override onBackPressed?

Answer (score 1):

`setupWithNavController` follows the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles). If you want to deviate from the Principles of Navigation, you'll need to write your own `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` for your `BottomNavigationView` that does what you want.

Comment: I didn't find anything about bottom navigation in this Principles of Navigation doc. I find this behavior kinda awkward.

Comment: Found this sample that should solve the problem (will try soon): https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample. Ian Lake, can you tell if the oficial support is in a alpha, beta or rc release?

Comment: @GuilhermeLimaPereira - the Principles of Navigation apply everywhere, not just to cases using bottom nav. It involved a lot of designers from both the Android and Material teams to build the Principles and giving users a clear sign post for when they are about to leave the app helped a lot in user studies.

Comment: @GuilhermeLimaPereira - that solution also returns to the start destination before leaving the app, as per the Principles of Navigation. The Fragment talk at AndroidDevSummit specifically talked about multiple back stack support coming soon. I suspect that sample will be updated as soon as it is available.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is the same of @StefMa: I have 3 tabs: A, B and C. When I go from Screen 1 to Screen 2 on tab A, then I go to Tab B, when I click in the tab A, it shows Screen 1, not Screen 2. So, the problem is not when leaving the app, but when changing tabs.

Comment: @GuilhermeLimaPereira - yep, that's what multiple back stacks helps with. The question here is about exiting the Activity without going back to the start destination, hence the answer. Seems like you have a different problem than the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

```
    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId != host.navController.currentDestination?.id) {
        host.navController.navigate(
            item.itemId, null,
            NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.nav_graph_main, false).build()
        )
    }
    return true
}
```

In use:

```
binding.bottomBar.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the action of navigating from **startDestination** (System in your app) to another fragment (sneez in your app) from where you want to close the app.
Just add the below two lines in action of startDestination to another fragment in navigation graph.

```
app:popUpTo="@id/homeFragment"
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```

**It worked for me.**

**Note:** *If you want to close the app from other fragment instead of startDestination*